# Total Shares Outstanding not working any longer in v5 pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have just tried this

```
//@version=5
indicator("MarketCap", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
Outstanding = request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "TOTAL_SHARES_OUTSTANDING", "FQ")
MarketCap = Outstanding*close
plotchar(MarketCap, "MarketCap", "", location = location.top)
```

for AAPL but its returning 0.

Anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: This was working before on AAPL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have 'TSO' identified, you need to switch your plotchar series to 'Outstanding'. Also it is `request.financial()` in version 5. Working code below

```
//@version=5
indicator("MarketCap", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
Outstanding = request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "TOTAL_SHARES_OUTSTANDING", "FQ")
MarketCap = Outstanding*close
plotchar(Outstanding, "TSO", "", location = location.top)
```

Here it is plotted with MarketCap per your comment request. Both seem to work fine.
[image]

Comment: Try plotting MarketCap instead of Outstanding, it always turns out to be zero. Your code is only showing the TSO but not the MarketCap. Seems it's a bug?

Comment: Plots just fine for me using MarketCap as well. Added a picture to my answer

Comment: oh yeah having more than one plot char messes things up. it works now with just one plotchar in the script. tx

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working!